# HVAC spray foam to prevent sweating on an inaccessible section of duct?

Tags: hvac, ducts

I have one small section of supply duct right above my furnace in the ceiling that is rusting due to condensation/sweat and is very difficult to access since it is between floors and behind several pipes.  Adding to the complication is that it looks like it's a dual duct where one duct splits into 2 so it's even more difficult to get access to the crevice between the 2 ducts.

Can I use duct spray foam to seal it up and stop the sweating and rust?

I think I can get a pole in there to scrape off some of the rust but will have heck of a time reaching in there to get insulation wrapped around it.

The face highlighted in blue is the rusty area - it starts up in the ceiling and comes down a ways towards the furnace.  Rust area is about 18" in length total.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just remember that any spot you don't get covered will continue to rust. You've been able to get _something_ in there to take the pics, so take some "after" pics to ensure you've got it all covered. Or, possibly, use a mechanic's "inspection mirror" (a mirror on a stick) to get a good look around to ensure you've got everything covered.

Comment: Is there a tool that has a sander on a stick ... I looked at maybe getting a standard drywall sanding head for a pole and think maybe it's a bit too thick and big... anything with just a round oval tip ... like a giant q-tip sander?

Comment: could I use a rust dissolver gel like rustoleum - or is that not safe for HVAC?

Comment: you could make your own sander by gluing sand paper to a wedge shape piece of wood. If you opt for the converter option (see answers), only sand to remove loose rust, then let the converter do its work.

Comment: ok I'll try to make my own sander wood to loosen rust and then use POR 15 to convert, then put insulation on top to prevent sweating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using a rust converter. Scratching away the rust will expose more non protected metal to start rusting again. The proper way to do it would be to replace the ductwork with new, but that may not be possible.

Using a rust converter will or should stop the rust and prevent more from occurring IF you get all the rust covered. This includes hard to reach places like crevasses and such.

The spray foam is a good idea, but be aware, the foam will start to expand in a few seconds as it emerges from the spray tip, obscuring anything that may not be covered behind it. It will go places you do not want, since aiming it may be a real trick in an area like you have there.

With spray foam you simply cannot "load it up" and expect that to work well. SPRAY FOAM MUST HAVE ROOM TO EXPAND! If not it will not be able to become the foam and will try to stay in a liquid state and superheat. I have seen this happen before where plastic pipes were in the same cavity, (Pex water lines) and they collapsed because of the heat and no pressure was on them at the time. When they were pressurized, the issue was found and needed to be replaced.

Comment: upvoted because I think converter is a good approach here, but provided my own answer for some more details that don't fit in comment

Comment: Thinking of using POR 15 since that seems highly rated - but am a bit worried about using it on HVAC for health/safety reasons if it gets into the airway or somehow drips down into the HVAC unit from a pinhole.  Are there special safety concerns or processes when using on HVAC ventilation duct?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove or stop the rust. Sanding in such a spot will not get it bare, so try applying a rust converter.

Put the **converter** (in **liquid** form) in a spray bottle and apply several times. It's safe to touch, but watch out for eyes/mouth/lungs while spraying.

Alternatively you can try to brush or roll on the converter in **gel** form. You'll find these products in home reno stores or automotive stores.

After several applications and enough waiting time (24 hrs between each) the rust will be converted, forming a protective layer. Do not scrape the converted rust (black "ferric tannate") off.

> Commercial rust converters are water-based and contain two primary active ingredients: tannic acid and an organic polymer. Tannic acid chemically converts the reddish iron oxides into bluish-black ferric tannate, a more stable material. The second active ingredient is an organic solvent such as 2-butoxyethanol (ethylene glycol monobutyl ether, trade name butyl cellosolve) that acts as a wetting agent and provides a protective primer layer in conjunction with an organic polymer emulsion

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_converter

Let thoroughly dry. Then you can spray on some **rust stop** **paint** or any oil based paint to seal it off better.

Finally apply **closed cell spray foam** to insulate and prevent future condensation.

Comment: Thinking of using POR 15 since that seems highly rated - but am a bit worried about using it on HVAC for health/safety reasons if it gets into the airway or somehow drips down into the HVAC unit from a pinhole. Are there special safety concerns or processes when using on HVAC ventilation duct?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey they are safe to touch, no toxic fumes after drying, and convert to a hard substance, so I'd say they're safe. Otherwise the safety precautions would be much higher (see manufacturer video for automotive example, no mask, no chemical gloves) and they'd tape off the break lines. If in doubt call them.